# Android studio vs Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

Recently I switched from Eclipse based Android SDK to Android Studio. I was working on some app in Eclipse that I now import into Android Studio. One thing I realized that when I run the app from Studio it takes more space(16 MB) on my cell phone than it was previously taking(11 MB) when it was run from Eclipse. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty hard to say what can cause this application "size growth" without checking the way how the application is built. 
I guess that it can be caused by some library (compatibility lib?) which is used during compilation but was not used in previous configuration of development environment.